Strategy for handling multiple EF Migrations
I need help formulating a strategy for handling situations where two or more team members create an EF migration independently and for different reasons. Every single time we've had this scenario so far, it completely messed up the DB snapshot as well as on occasion the migration too. Our migrations are more complex than the normal boilerplate since it contains seed data and some other things I can't discuss. But in essence what happens is that when we have two or more migrations, there are always merge conflictsin our snapshots and no clear path to resolve them.
I think it's mostly due to having one snapshot but having

Option 1: one migration at a time (which will mean some team members having to rebuild their migration after another has been added): ie. team members need to work together. Option 2: migrations may not be the answer in your case; they work really well for easy cases but that doesn't mean they are always the right answer (the build overhead of all those lines of generated C# can be an issue). Go old school and write SQL.

If you use the built in seeding mechanism it should be fairly straightforward to just recreate the migration when merging. Assuming the "other things" do not involve lots of manual editing of the migrations.

When we create PR, we mention that it is [MIGRATION], which means High Priority review. After review developer and if there are new migration merged into develop  branch, should revert migration, merge with develop, and create migration again. Then merge into develop.

If the additional migrations are autogenerated you could delete both when merging and create a new one that contains both changes.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv that's a good option. Please make it an answer?

@jeb same thing. Please make it an answer.

Assuming you have a main development branch, for example, develop. If someone merges a migration into develop, it is not safe to merge migration code directly. Here’s how we handle this situation:

We add [MIGRATION] to the name of Pull Requests that contain migrations. This indicates a High Priority review for the team to avoid migration conflicts.
When a PR is reviewed, you should check that there are no new migrations in the develop branch at the time of your PR.
If there are already applied migrations in develop, you should REVERT your migration(s), merge with develop, recreate the migrations, and then merge into develop as soon as possible. If someone pushes a migration into develop during this short period, you should repeat this step.

We are not doing this yet, but merging into develop can be restricted by DevOps pipelines:

If your PR has changes in DataContextModelSnapshot.cs, the pipeline should check that your PR branch has all commits that changed this file since the branching time. Merging with develop resolves this.
If not all commits are found, merging should be blocked. Go back to step 3 to fix this.


Thank you. That does sound like a good idea.
